# / in urlpatterns django

Tags: django, django-urls

I am a beginner in django and don't understand the meaning "/" in urlpatterns. Here is the urlpatterns in my project urls. My first app's name is first.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first', include("first.urls"))
]
```

I found that it didn't work unless I amended it to following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first/', include("first.urls"))
]
```

I don't understand what the meaning of '/' is. I googled but did not find an answer. Could anyone help me on this?

Another question is that the double quotes and single quote could be used either way. But is there any convention or better practice that I can follow to use single or double quote? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No convention on the quotes. See what is specified in PEP8 (Style Guide for Python Code) on this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: it is used as a separator for the `first` and for the URL paths in your `first` app.

You are including the `urlpatterns` of the `first` app. Imagine that this app has as URL:

```
# first/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', foo)
]
```

Without the slash, the path to trigger `foo` is `/firstfoo/` so it appends the two.

If you work with a slash, the path to trigger `foo` is `/first/foo`.

Comment: I just tried it and it did work. Thanks a lot. How about the question regarding to two quotes and single quote? Is there any convention to follow?

Comment: @johnwow: no, PEP-8 says that people can pick any of the two. But usually it is better to be consistent. Furthermore if you want to write a single quote in the string, you work with double quotes and vice versa, so `"'"` or `'"'`.